# Codecept not showing any php unit test results

Tags: php, codeception

I'm completely new to php and codecept and have been following a tutorial, but I'm not getting any test results when I try to run a simple unit test.

My project structure looks as follows:

[image]

The code for the classes is:

**Config.php**

```
<?php
//Have we already been here?
if (!defined('DB_HOST')) {
 
    // Define DB Params
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "");
    define("DB_NAME", "philter");
    
    // Define URL
    define("ROOT_URL", "http://bit703.module2/");
 
    // Add some helpful filepath constants
    define('APP_ROOT', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/');
    define('VIEW_ROOT', APP_ROOT . 'Views/');
 
    // Tell this sytem we are in a development environment
    define('DEV_ENV', true);
}
```

**Utils.php**

```
<?php
 
/* 
 * spl_autoload_register() allows you to register multiple functions 
 * (or static methods from your own Autoload class) 
 * that PHP will put into a stack/queue and call sequentially 
 * when a "new Class" is declared. 
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
 
    /*
     *  Project-specific namespace prefix
     */
    $prefix = 'BIT703\\';
  
    /*
     *  Does the class use the namespace prefix?
     */
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }
  
    /*
     *  Get the relative class name
     */
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);
    print("<pre>".print_r($relative_class, 1)."</pre>");
  
    /*
     *  Replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
     *  separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
     *  with .php
     */
    $file = APP_ROOT . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';
    print("<pre>".print_r($file, 1)."</pre>");
  
    die();
    
    /*
     *  if the file exists, require it
     */
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
  });
  $router = new \BIT703\Classes\Router();
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

require  'config.php';
require 'utils.php';
```

**RouterTest.php**

```
<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../src/App/bootstrap.php');

use \BIT703\Classes\Router as Router;

class RouterTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    /**
     * @var \UnitTester
     */
    protected $tester;
    
    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testSomeFeature()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('\BIT703\Classes\Router', $this->router);
    }

}
```

This is the output I'm getting when I run the test:

```
$ php vendor/bin/codecept run unit RouterTest
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.18
Powered by PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
<pre>Classes\Router</pre>. 
<pre>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bit703/module2/src/App/Classes/Router.php</pre>
```

If I comment out "require 'utils.php';" from bootstrap.utils, then I get a proper test failure message, but as soon as it's included, it stops working.

Can anyone see what I have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you created default Codeception directory structure with unit, functional and acceptance directories.

Test files must be placed in one of these directories, so move RouterTest.php file to unit directory.

Comment: The test is already sitting in the Unit directory (just doesn't look like it in the screenshot).

Comment: Execution stops because there is `die();` line in your Utils.php file.

Comment: Thanks Naktibalda. I thought that was the case, but it was a direct copy and paste from the tutorial, so I wasn't sure if that was the problem.